# Synonyms for "as the saying goes"

Tags: idioms

When writing where I want to present quotes, I've used the phrase "as the saying goes...". Is there any other phrase that can be used to present a quote or proverb ?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is one sentence adverb usage of **proverbially**:

> *proverbially* [adverb]: in a way that relates to a well-known saying or phrase:
>
> - *We must be living in those “interesting times” often proverbially mentioned.*
> - *It is proverbially impossible to please everyone.*
>
> ...
>
> - *Proverbially enough, it rained on the plain today.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/proverbially)]

The [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/proverbial) definition of the adjective is highly relevant:

> **proverbial** [adjective]:
>
> You use *proverbial* to show that you know the way you are describing
> something is one that is often used or is part of a popular saying.
>
> - *The limousine sped off down the road in the proverbial cloud of dust.*

......................

Quotes, when directly attributed, are often introduced by the expressions **in / to use the words of [the]**.

- *In the words of George Bernard Shaw, “A happy family is but an earlier heaven.”*

[[Madhubun Educational Books_Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/madhubunbooks/videos/in-the-words-of-george-bernard-shaw-a-happy-family-is-but-an-earlier-heavenwishi/332825394856084/)]

- *To use the words of Albert Einstein. (1879-1955) again: “The intellect has little to do on the road to discovery. There is a leap of consciousness, call it.*

[[A de Bruin_De Gruyter_Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to+use+the+words+of+Albert+%22&ei=3kweYcyLBdHVgQbG5pPADA&oq=%22to+use+the+words+of+Albert+%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKsCOgcIABBHELADOgQIABAeOggIABAIEAcQHjoGCAAQCBAeOgUIABCGA0oECEEYAFDH5QJY8oMDYLKVA2gBcAJ4AIABb4gBtASSAQM3LjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjM8p7Dib3yAhXRasAKHUbzBMgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)]

- *'The private individual who gives his fifty hundreds to a particular Institution,' to use the words of the Hull and Eastern Counties' Herald* ...

[Henry Woodcock_The Hero of the Humber_Amazon](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hu5RDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=%22to+use+the+words+of+%22&source=bl&ots=zAikeTr72C&sig=ACfU3U3cQfYysZxeRKkt0ZgE8P9x1BNRrQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20use%20the%20words%20of%20%22&f=false)]

- *By the end of October the last Turkish regular had quitted Magyar soil, and, to use the words of a contemporary observer, one quarter of Hungary was* ....

[[YourDictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to+use+the+words+of+%22&ei=ekweYfLEH8KP8gLKsKbIAQ&oq=%22to+use+the+words+of+%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAghEBYQHRAeMggIIRAWEB0QHjIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeMggIIRAWEB0QHjIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeMggIIRAWEB0QHjIICCEQFhAdEB4yCAghEBYQHRAeOgcIABBHELADSgQIQRgAUPXCBVjqgAZg3oIGaAFwAngAgAFXiAGUBZIBAjEymAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjy6eGTib3yAhXCh1wKHUqYCRkQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)]

Answer (score 0):

> You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink, **as they say**/ **as the saying has it**.